# Class cast Exception when reading an saved array list (object) from a file

Tags: java, arraylist, classcastexception, objectinputstream

I want to actually read data from a file into an array list of a `Flight_registrie`  class. I am able to save an array list in a file, but when I try to read from the file, it's not working and giving a class cast exception. I also tried to get values in the array list directly, but it didn't work. 
Can you tell me what should I write to read data from a file into an array list?

```
try {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(" Flight Registrie.bin"));

    Flight_registrie b =(Flight_registrie) ois.readObject();
    alr.add(b);
    ois.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("\t\t\tFile not Found.");    
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An I/O error occurs");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("\t\tClass Flight_registrie not found ");
}
```

and below code is how i took input .

```
try {al.add(a);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(" Flight Registrie.bin"));
    oos.writeObject(al);
    System.out.println("Data Saved");
    al.clear();
oos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println("An I/O error occurs");
}
```

Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class
source__module.Flight_registrie (java.util.ArrayList is in module
java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; source__module.Flight_registrie is in
unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at source__module.Functions.get_data(Functions.java:64)
    at file.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:41)
```

Comment: It looks like your code is trying to read a `Flight_registrie` object, not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: ya it is but how can i read an array list from the file,

Comment: It seems you write into file ArrayList but read list item. You need to update question with serialization code.

Comment: i edited the other code which shows how i am taking input . so what should i read from file.

Comment: If you write a banana, you must read a banana. Not an apple. Not a box of bananas. If you want to read a registry, you must write a registry. If you write an ArrayList, you must read an ArrayList.

Comment: Also note that serialization won't produce text. So naming your file with a `.txt` extension is not the best idea. And please, respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: do file type bin will work

Comment: @justknowledge the name of the file has nothing to do with your error.

Comment: alr is an array list of same as i used in writing in file.   but i am not finding any way in every source how i can read in array list from file.                                                     i also tried                
               alr.add(  ois.readobject() );

Comment: You can. And your code does that already. But you're trying to cast the ArrayList you read into a `Flight_registrie`. That's what is failing, because an ArrayList is not a Flight_registrie. It's an ArrayList. So you need to cast what you read to `ArrayList<WhateverIsContainedInTheList>`. It's right there, clearly explained in the error message: *java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class
source__module.Flight_registrie*

Comment: ArrayList <Flight_registrie> alr=new ArrayList<Flight_registrie>();              Like this .

Comment: We have no idea of what you **wrote**. Suppose it's an ArrayList<Banana>. If that's what you wrote, then you must cast what you read to ArrayList<Banana>: `ArrayList<Banana> list = (ArrayList<Banana>) ois.readObject();`. Makes sense? What you read is what you write. As simple as that.

Comment: @JB Nizet i got it readobject(); is  returning the array list that's what causing the issue on casting. thanks you cleared my many doubts about reading from file and array list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are saving a List in your file. But while reading you are trying to read a List into Flight_registrie.

That id why the error is coming as you are trying to cast an ArrayList object into and object of Flight_registrie class. The faulty line is :

```
 Flight_registrie b =(Flight_registrie) ois.readObject();
```

Try changing it to this :

```
List<Flight_registrie> b =(List<Flight_registrie>) ois.readObject();
```

And this should fix the problem.

Comment: One should read the object of a class of which the object was written in the file in the very first place. List can be written and read from files as they implement Serializable by default.